# flask_socketio concurrency using eventlet

Tags: socket.io, flask-socketio, eventlet

I am trying to handle multiple concurrent requests using `flask_socketio` and `eventlet`. However, it does not work as expected: When function `test1()` is running, it blocks the execution of function `test2()` as seen in the output log.

How can I achieve that the server handles both requests simultaneously?

**Server (Python):**

```py
import eventlet
eventlet.monkey_patch()

from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, send, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app, async_mode='eventlet')

@socketio.on('test1')
def test1():
    print('test1 started')
    do_complicated_calculation() # takes some time
    print('test1 done')

@socketio.on('test2')
def test2():
    print('test2')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

**Client (JavaScript):**

```js
import io from 'socket.io-client';

socket = io('http://localhost:5000');
socket.emit('test1');
socket.emit('test2');
```

**Expected Output:**

```
test1 started
test2
test1 done
```

**Actual Output:**

```
test1 started
test1 done
test2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed on GitHub, you need to insert `socketio.sleep(0)` calls as often as you can inside your long computation, ideally inside a loop so that it happens at regular intervals. That will allow the eventlet scheduler to give the CPU to your second task while the first task is running.